# make a choice list from a field into other field through the Foreign key Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models connected with the foreign key with each other as below :

```
class Service(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    counter = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.title}'


class Reservation(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Service, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    turn    = models.GeneratedField(expression='',
output_field=models.CharField(max_length=1),
                                    db_persist=True,)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.user}'
```

What I want to do is that `turn` field in `Reservation` get option `choices` and choice values are from 1 to `service.counter`. `service` is the foreign key here. for example if `counter` in `Service` model is 5 the `turn` field in `Reservation` would be something like this :
`turn = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=[1,2,3,4,5])`. for loop won't work obviously :) .
Should I create a `property` field or Meta class ?
anyway, How can I change my field like this?
Any help will appreciate and grateful.

**after one hour searching, I think for a better approach to solve this. I'v change `turn` field into a Generated field so we make a query and assert it to the database, but I'm not sure how to do that?
Can anyone help?**

Comment: At the time when the user is asked to select the choices for `turn`, is the `service` already stored to the `Reservation`-object? Remember, When the `Reservation` is freshly created, the user 1. selects the service 2. selects the turn.... but without a site reload django has no chance to pass appropriate choices to the `turn`. In the latter case it becomes a "problem" of the front end.

Comment: Thanks for your mention, but yes. This is a reservation system that requires for Service and Products,so service object is created before the Reservation model get fired off! and  there is a link for each service in frontend to connect only available services in Service for Reservation model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Only `Service` exists already and you want to create a complete new `Reservation` and let the user choose connected `Service`. The answer to this Option is most likely not found within django, the backend, but has to be handled within the frontend. Reason being that it requires to switch possible choices for `turn` on the fly when the user selects a different connected `Service`.

Option 2: An initial `Reservation`-Object with connected `Service` already exists when the user is asked to select `turn`. This can be done by django. Not on the models.py level though. This logic has to go to forms.py. We need a model form, that only needs the `turn` field populated.

```py
class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ['turn']
        widgets = {
            'turn': forms.Select(),  # Set the widget for the 'turn' field to Select
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        service_instance = kwargs.pop('service_instance', None)
        super(ReservationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if service_instance:
            # Set the choices for the 'turn' field based on the service instance's counter
            self.fields['turn'].choices = [(i, i) for i in range(service_instance.counter + 1)]
        else:
            # If no service instance is provided, default to an empty list
            self.fields['turn'].choices = []


# views.py
service_instance = Service.objects.get(id=service_id)
form = ReservationForm(service_instance=service_instance)
```

Above shows how to do dynamic forms. Basically you are selecting up front in the view what you want to pass to the form. Then within the `__init__` method you capture that and set it accordingly.

Since you said that this form is always already bound to an object and therefore is connected to a service already you can also go for this option:

```py
class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = ['turn']
        widgets = {
            'turn': forms.Select(),  # Set the widget for the 'turn' field to Select
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReservationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # next line checks if an object is already connected to the form and a service connected
        service_id = self.data.get('service') if self.is_bound else None

        if service_id:
            try:
                service_instance = Service.objects.get(id=service_id)
                # Set the choices for the 'turn' field based on the service instance's counter
                self.fields['turn'].choices = [(i, i) for i in range(service_instance.counter + 1)]
            except Service.DoesNotExist:
                # If the service does not exist, default to an empty list
                self.fields['turn'].choices = []
        else:
            # If no service ID is provided, default to an empty list
            self.fields['turn'].choices = []

# views.py
# here you need to pass an instance to the form
form = ReservationForm(request.POST, instance=Reservation.objects.get(id=1)
```